# Merge objects with corresponding key values from two different arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I've got two arrays that have multiple objects

```
[
     {
         "name":"paul",
         "employee_id":"8"
     }
]

[
     {
         "years_at_school": 6,
         "department":"Mathematics",
         "e_id":"8"
     }
]
```

How can I achieve the following with either ES6 or Lodash?

```
[
     {
         "name":"paul",
         "employee_id":"8"
         "data": {
             "years_at_school": 6
             "department":"Mathematics",
             "e_id":"8"
         }
     }
]
```

I can merge but I'm not sure how to create a new child object and merge that in.

Code I've tried:

```
school_data = _.map(array1, function(obj) {
    return _.merge(obj, _.find(array2, {employee_id: obj.e_id}))
})
```

This merges to a top level array like so (which is not what I want):

```
{
     "name":"paul",
     "employee_id":"8"
     "years_at_school": 6
     "department":"Mathematics",
     "e_id":"8"
 }
```

The connector between these two is `"employee_id"` and `"e_id"`.

It's imperative that it's taken into account that they could be 1000 objects in each array, and that the only way to match these objects up is by `"employee_id"` and `"e_id"`.

Comment: possible answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match up `employee_id` and `e_id` you should iterate through the first array and create an object keyed to `employee_id`. Then you can iterate though the second array and add the data to the particular id in question. Here's an example with an extra item added to each array:

```js
let arr1 = [
    {
        "name":"mark",
        "employee_id":"6"
    },
    {
        "name":"paul",
        "employee_id":"8"
    }
]

let arr2 = [
    {
        "years_at_school": 6,
        "department":"Mathematics",
        "e_id":"8"
    },
    {
        "years_at_school": 12,
        "department":"Arr",
        "e_id":"6"
    }
    
]

// empObj will be keyed to item.employee_id 
let empObj = arr1.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.employee_id] = item
    return obj
}, {})

//  now lookup up id and add data for each object in arr2
arr2.forEach(item=>
    empObj[item.e_id].data = item
)

// The values of the object will be an array of your data
let merged = Object.values(empObj)
console.log(merged)
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Meyer, The objects aren't always aligned, they have to be merged on the keys 'employee_id' & 'e_id'.

Comment: Hi @PaulSimmons, you have two arrays. By aligned I mean you want the data in `arr1[n]` to be merged with `arr2[n]`. If `arr2` was in a different order it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry @Mark Meyer, I'm confused on the aligned part. My main concern is that if there's an "employee_id" of 6, arr2 isn't going to go in there because it has an "e_id" of value 8.

Comment: @PaulSimmons, sorry I didn't notice the e_id -> employee_id relation. I've edit the answer. I think it's closer to what you are looking for. It shouldn't care about the array order.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform two nested O(n) loops (map+find), you'll end up with O(n^2) performance. A typical alternative is to create intermediate indexed structures  so the whole thing is O(n). A functional approach with lodash:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const dataByEmployeeId = _(array2).keyBy('e_id');
const result = array1.map(o => ({...o, data: dataByEmployeeId.get(o.employee_id)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you:

```js
var mainData = [{
   name: "paul",
   employee_id: "8"
}];

var secondaryData = [{
  years_at_school: 6,
  department: "Mathematics",
  e_id: "8"
}];

var finalData = mainData.map(function(person, index) {
  person.data = secondaryData[index];
  return person;
});
```

Sorry, I've also fixed a missing coma in the second object and changed some other stuff.

With latest Ecmascript versions:

```js
const mainData = [{
   name: "paul",
   employee_id: "8"
}];

const secondaryData = [{
  years_at_school: 6,
  department: "Mathematics",
  e_id: "8"
}];

// Be careful with spread operator over objects.. it lacks of browser support yet! ..but works fine on latest Chrome version for example (69.0)
const finalData = mainData.map((person, index) => ({ ...person, data: secondaryData[index] }));
```

Comment: Hi @Juan Elfers, if e_id is 7 and employee_id is 8, this would still merge, which it shouldn't do.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't notice that.. thought that the arrays were ordered!

Comment: What do you propose to do with the "missing" values..? I'd need more info about that.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach just using vanilla js `map` with a loop to match the employee ids and add the data from the second array to the matching object from the first array. My guess is that the answer from [@MarkMeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) is probably faster.

```js
const arr1 = [{ "name": "paul", "employee_id": "8" }];
const arr2 = [{ "years_at_school": 6, "department": "Mathematics", "e_id": "8" }];
const results = arr1.map((obj1) => {
  for (const obj2 of arr2) {
    if (obj2.e_id === obj1.employee_id) {
      obj1.data = obj2;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return obj1;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: If you want to loop the slow way, just use `_.find()` as OP did.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that both arrays will always have the same size. It also suggests that you want to put the contents of `array2` within the field `data` of the elements with the same index in `array1`. If those assumptions are correct, then:

```
// Array that will receive the extra data
const teachers = [
    { name: "Paul", employee_id: 8 },
    { name: "Mariah", employee_id: 10 }
];

// Array with the additional data
const extraData = [
    { years_at_school: 6, department: "Mathematics", e_id: 8 },
    { years_at_school: 8, department: "Biology", e_id: 10 },
];

// Array.map will iterate through all indices, and gives both the
const merged = teachers.map((teacher, index) => Object.assign({ data: extraData[index] }, teacher));
```

---

However, if you want the data to be added to the employee with an "id" matching in both arrays, you need to do the following:

```
// Create a function to obtain the employee from an ID
const findEmployee = id => extraData.filter(entry => entry.e_id == id);

merged = teachers.map(teacher => {
    const employeeData = findEmployee(teacher.employee_id);

    if (employeeData.length === 0) {
        // Employee not found
        throw new Error("Data inconsistency");
    }

    if (employeeData.length > 1) {
        // More than one employee found
        throw new Error("Data inconsistency");
    }

    return Object.assign({ data: employeeData[0] }, teacher);
});
```